# Returning HTTP 403 substatus from Asp.Net WebApi controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-403

I'd like to return Http 403 errors from my Asp.Net WebApi controllers when the user does not have permission to perform certain tasks.

However, I'd like to use a [substatus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403#403_substatus_error_codes_for_IIS) on this to give further details about the error, along with the error message.

At the moment, what I get is

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Read access forbidden
```

but what I'd like to see is

```
HTTP/1.1 403.2 Read access forbidden
```

The code I'm using currently:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public EnrollmentDetail Details(int id)
    {
        var enrollmentDetail = _context.GetEnrollmentDetail(id);

        if (!enrollmentDetail.R)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Read access forbidden"
                });
        }

        return enrollmentDetail;
    }
```

I can't find any information any where on how to add these sub-statuses to the response.  Is there any way it can be done with the built-in classes?  If not, is there a way to write a custom `HttpException` which could do this for me?

Comment: I can't find an exact answer but I think these two links should help.
http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's because sub-statuses are not part of the HTTP spec and should not be used.  If you want to send more details about the problem you encountered, take a look at [Json-problem](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-04)